# ASMX service returns only part of the list items, not all of existing items

Tags: 2010, list, web-services

I can see that there are 50 items on site in list1, but ASMX-service returns me 34 items. When I call `GetList("list1")` service returns me a description of the list. This description contains an attribute `ItemsCount` which value equals to a real count of list items (50 in this case).

Here is my code:

```
XElement ndQuery = new XElement("Query", "");
XElement ndViewFields = new XElement("ViewFields", "");
XElement ndQueryOptions = new XElement("QueryOptions", "");
ndQueryOptions.Add(new XElement("IncludeMandatoryColumns") { Value = "FALSE" });

XElement list = client.GetListItems(
                        "list1",
                        null,
                        ndQuery,
                        ndViewFields,
                        null,
                        ndQueryOptions,
                        null);
```

Comment: If you don't include a query, the web service will query the default view.  Does your default view have any filtering on it?

Comment: Derek, post the answer, I'll mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't include a query, the web service will query the default view. Either change the default view to include all items, or write a caml query that includes all items.